# Is there a gui options for passwordstore

Tags: software-rec, gui, password-store

So while I personally prefer to use passwordstore via the commandline as it is intended. I am pushing for my co-workers to use it. It works perfect for what we need, which is a centralized place to share sensitive data such as passwords, secret keys, etc, and it's all encrypted, yay! However, some employees are not that savvy with the command line and would not use it. So I'm looking for a solution of how I can bring a more comfortable to those employees. Because right now the running candidates are tools like 1password, lastpass, and keepass. Which I'm not the biggest fan of running that on my machine. I know there are iOS and Android gui's available, so I figured maybe somewhere there are some desktop options. Mostly we use Mac's, though there are a handful that use Windows. I know that will be a bit of a stretch trying to find Windows solutions.

Comment: What's `passwordstore`?

Comment: Did you need a tool to manage the passwords on your system?

Comment: @anon [passwordstore](https://www.passwordstore.org/) is a encrypted password db.

Comment: @GAD3R I have a tool to manage passwords. It's passwordstore. I'm looking for a gui client for passwordstore specifically that is friendly to employees that are not savvy with the command line.

Comment: If you're looking for something that works on Windows as well as Linux, [softwarerecs.se] would be a better place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am dumb. It has it right on their home page. [GUI Client](https://qtpass.org/) Geez it's been ages since I've looked at it. I'll leave this post here in case anyone misses this as well. Wish google searches would have been a little more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [`ripasso`](https://github.com/cortex/ripasso) and its unmaintained-but-possibly-slightly-more-feature complete predecessor [`gopass`](https://github.com/cortex/gopass)

Comment: Be aware that there seem at least two if not three implementations named "gopass". There's the one you mentioned, then there was "gopass.pw" (which might be the same as you mentioned, not sure) and then there is https://github.com/aviau/gopass (not a GUI tool but just a reimplementation of pass in Go).

Answer (score 0):

There are (in the meanwhile I guess) [QtPass](https://qtpass.org/) as well as [Plasma Pass](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-pass).

You also might be interested in the TUI client called [upass](https://github.com/Kwpolska/upass).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few, actually.

Here is the full list: https://www.passwordstore.org/#other

(all text/descriptions are directly reproduced from the link above)

- [passmenu](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/dmenu): an **extremely useful and awesome** dmenu script
- [qtpass](http://qtpass.org/): cross-platform GUI client
- [Android-Password-Store](https://github.com/zeapo/Android-Password-Store#readme): Android app
- [passforios](https://mssun.github.io/passforios/): iOS app

  [pass-ios](https://github.com/davidjb/pass-ios#readme): (older) iOS app

  [passff](https://github.com/jvenant/passff#readme): Firefox plugin

  [browserpass](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/browserpass#readme): Chrome plugin

  [Pass4Win](https://github.com/mbos/Pass4Win#readme): Windows client

  [pext_module_pass](https://github.com/Pext/pext_module_pass#readme): module for Pext

  [gopass](https://github.com/cortex/gopass#readme): Go GUI app

  [upass](https://github.com/Kwpolska/upass#readme): interactive console UI

  [alfred-pass](https://github.com/CGenie/alfred-pass#readme): Alfred integration

  [pass-alfred](https://github.com/MatthewWest/pass-alfred#readme): Alfred integration

  [simple-pass-alfred](https://github.com/johanthoren/simple-pass-alfred): Alfred integration

  [pass.applescript](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/pass.applescript): OS X integration

  [pass-git-helper](https://github.com/languitar/pass-git-helper): git credential integration

  [password-store.el](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/emacs): an emacs package

  [XMonad.Prompt.Pass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Prompt-Pass.html): prompt for Xmonad

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/407419)

Comment: Thank you all who have answered. Especially the recent ones; fourstepper, Axel Beckert, Greenonline. My apologies I have let this one slip and did not close this one out years ago. Your answers will be very helpful to others, but I will close this one out as I no longer need this, and the question got answered by myself. I might not have had the ability to answer my own questions at the time. Again, my apologies and thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

`pass-simple` - Multi platform gui (Qt,QML,c++):

It has binaries for MACOS and downloadable static linked zip folder for ubuntu 20.04 at:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pass-simple/

You can compile it yourself very easily, see readme:

https://github.com/shemeshg/pass-simple-qt